# C++ Best approach to filtering bytes in a stream

Tags: c++, filter, stream, buffer

I'm learning c++ (coming from a C and Java university coursework) and today I want to write a class that filters the bytes taken from a generic stream and writes its output to another stream.

To be coincise, let's say I want to make a class that base64-encodes the input and writes the output to stdout.

In bash I would write:

```bash
echo "some input data" | base64
```

In C++ i want to implement a class `MyB64Encoder` that would behave like this:

```cpp
std::cout << myB64EncoderObject << "some input data";

//Alternatively, is it possible to make it like this?
std::cout << MyB64Encoder << "some input data";
```

The thing is, the `myB64EncoderObject` has, of course, to maintain an internal state and an internal buffer. To prevent blocking and excessive memory usage, it must be able to read and process small chunks of data and output each one of them immediately after it has been processed.

There are a few more things to take care of:

- The object must wait for the output stream to be able to receive data
- The object must throw an error if there is no stream reading from it (kinda like a broken pipe?)

What would be the best approach to a problem like this, in terms of efficiency? How would I implement it in modern C++1x?

Comment: Wrap a stream (or wrap a streambuffer).

Answer (score 2):

The existing things that behave like this:

```
std::cout << myB64EncoderObject << "some input data";
```

are [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) (eg. std::boolalpha, std::hex, ...). However, these just set flags on the stream that it already knows how to interpret.

If you want to keep that syntax, you'll need to something more complex, namely an intermediate wrapper:

```
class B64Wrapper {
    std::ostream &os_;
    B64Encoder &enc_; // only if your encoder is really stateful

public:
    B64Wrapper() = delete;
    B64Wrapper(B64Wrapper&&) = default;
    B64Wrapper(B64Wrapper const&) = default;

    B64Wrapper(std::ostream &os, B64Encoder &enc) : os_(os), enc_(enc) {}


    template <typename T>
    B64Wrapper& operator<< (B64Wrapper &self, T val) {
        self.enc_.encode(os_, val);
        return self;
    }
};

B64Wrapper operator<< (std::ostream &os, B64Encoder &enc) {
    return B64Wrapper(os, enc);
}
```

(note you still need to write the `B64Encoder::encode(std::ostream &, T value)` method).

If your encoder isn't really stateful, you don't need a reference to it, and declare `B64Encoder` as an empty tag type with a global instance to get the same effect - in that case it only exists to select the `operator<<` overload.

The other approach is to write a [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) implementation which encodes the input to `sputc`/`sputn`/`xsputn`. It can forward everything else to a wrapped streambuf or to the base class, depending on what you inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class MyEncoder
{
public:
private:
    std::ostream* os = nullptr;

    // This overload deals with:
    // std::cout << myEncoder ...
    friend MyEncoder& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyEncoder& me)
    {
        // grab a reference to the target output stream
        me.os = &os;
        return me;
    }

    // This overload deals with:
    // std::cout << MyEncoder() ...
    friend MyEncoder& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyEncoder&& me)
    {
        // the temporary is currently bound to the l-value parameter me
        // so we can just pass this call on to the previous overload
        return os << me;
    }

    // This overload deals with:
    // myEncoder << <anything else>
    template<typename T>
    friend MyEncoder& operator<<(MyEncoder& me, T const& v)
    {
        // only encode if there is an output stream to send the data to
        // this will only be set if one of the above overloads was called
        if(!me.os)
            throw std::runtime_error("no stream to receive encoded data");

        // do your encoding here
        (*me.os) << "{encoded: " << v << "}";

        return me;
    }
};
```

Basically to achieve this:

```
std::cout << MyEncoder() << "some data: " << 45;
//                                        ^ calls operator<<(MyEncoder&, 45)
//                       ^ calls operator<<(MyEncoder&, "some data: ")
//        ^ calls operator<<(std::cout, MyEncoder())
```

The calls go left to right.

It may seem a little involved but it is basically covering 3 different call possibilities.

```
MyEncoder encoder;
std::cout << encoder; // MyEncoder& object

std::cout << MyEncoder(); // (temporary) MyEncoder&& object

encoder << "anything else" // A MyEncoder& receiving any other object
```

The first 2 operators are overloaded to set the internal `std::ostream*` and the third operator is overloaded to do the actual encoding.